# How do i dissable the bootstrap popover on page resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the `bootstrap` `popover` for a `drop down` menu. Is there any way I could disable the `popover` function either with `css media queries` or by `jquery` on page resize and make the menu visible and vertical in mobile view.

Here is what I've tried:

```
<a href="#"  id="ble" class="ved" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-content='
<ul class="nav nav-pill">
<li><a href="#" >home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" >home</a></li>
 </ul>
 '>Toggle popover</a>
</div>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('#ble').popover({html:true}); 
$(window).on('resize', function () {
if ($window.width() > 300) {
   $('#ble').unbind('popover');
 }
  });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be more easier if you are doing with media queries from CSS.

```
@media (max-width: 300px) {
   #ble {display: none;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using matchMedia - Support from IE10 above.

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
   $('#element').popover('hide'); // Hides popover
   $('#element').popover('destroy') //Destroys 
} else {
  activate the popup here
}
```

Use https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/ for matchMedia polyfill